# Java Custom List to String Array

Tags: java

My Class is Below, how do i cast `ArrayList<TestA>` to `String[]` which only have `ItemText` values without any for loop. Which is the best way?

```
public class TestA implements Serializable {
    private String ItemSrc;
    private String ItemText;

    public String getItemText() {
        return this.ItemText;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why no for loop? What about a while loop? Using java8? Streams? Why does it have to be a cast?

Comment: You can't. You have to iterate over all the elements and place only the ``ItemText`` in your newly created array.

Comment: List class is generic and must be load at first. For other controls only use a value from this class one property. So i must cast to list class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have `ArrayList<TestA> tests` and can use `java-8`

```
tests.stream().map(TestA::getItemText).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Better than my answer as it eliminates the need for a cast. Good answer!

Comment: *can use java-8* dangerous assumption. What to do in case of java 7?

Comment: is java-8 safe for android ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use java8's streams:

```
ArrayList<TestA> l = [...]; // your arrayList
String[] array = (String[]) l.stream().map(a->a.ItemText).toArray();
```